# How can I enable crash dumps in Catch2 C++ tests in Azure DevOps CI/CD pipeline?

Tags: c++, testing, crash-dumps, catch2, procdump

I'm developing a C++ software product for Windows. I wrote tests for it using the Catch2 framework. They are automated in CI/CD pipeline in Azure Dev Ops (ADO). What I would like to do is to get a crash dump (.dmp file) automatically created and saved in this ADO pipeline, when there is a crash in my code (e.g. unhandled exception). I don't see anything in Catch2 framework to allow crash dump collection. I'm using the tool procdump.exe elsewhere to create crash dump, and I'm wondering if there is a way to run this tool with my Catch2 tests to get a dump when a crash happens. Any tips on how that can be done, or using other tools, will be helpful, thanks!
Darren

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using procdump.exe to launch my Catch2 test executable. For example:

```
 procdump.exe -ma -e -x CrashDumpFolder MyCatch2Tests.exe  <test arguments>
```

Since in my case MyCatch2Tests.exe runs the tests in a single process, the above should work. If I have a crash in my tests a full crash dump (*.dmp file) will be created in the CrashDumpFolder.